# How to programmatically get the radius value of the corners of a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, rounded-corners

I need to fetch some layout values from a view: position on screen, width, height and the value that defines the corners of this view.

The first parameters are pretty trivial to get using `View.getWidth()`, `View.getHeight()` and `View.getLocationOnScreen`.

But what about the corners radius? How can I retrieve this information from a view?

Comment: How is this value set inside your xml?

Comment: @user3249477, as @dergolem mentioned, the shape value is set on a shape drawable (after a tree of other xmls to set elements like `background/selector/layer-list/item/shape` and finally `corners android:radius`)

Comment: Please post the xml files of the shape drawable you're using and the View to which the drawable is set.